# Android - No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT

Tags: android

I'm getting this exception when I try to open the Navigation Drawer from the right
Exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT
at

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

My Layout file :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Is there anything I'm doing Wrong?
Thanks for your Assistance.

Answer (score 6):

Anyways I got it working myself,For others who are finding difficulty to solve, Here's what I have did, I changed  `android:layout_gravity="right"` of the list view to  `android:layout_gravity="end"` it started  working fine.

Comment: If you want to open from the left, just use the code:
    android:layout_gravity="start"